# How to tag users using Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am looking to create a command in order to tag certain users automatically using their username eg. "@RYAN#9602" whenever a switch statement case is executed. Currently the problem that I'm experiencing in that whenever I do try to tag users, it just writes "@RYAN#9602" into the text channel and doesn't actually tag them.

This is what I have tried:

```
var players = [
"@RYAN#9602"
]



switch(args[0].toLowerCase()){

 case "play":
            message.channel.send(players.join('\n'));
            break;
}
```

So in summary, using Discord.JS, how do I make the bot actually tag the user so that they will get 'pinged' instead of just sending a message of their name into the text channel?

Comment: What response? That's not in your question.

Comment: @Rob What do you mean?

Comment: `I have tried researching it but I did not understand their response.`

Comment: **Don't post links to third party sites to show us anything. Post the information/code/data in your question!**

Comment: First, type `\@RYAN#9602` in chat manually. Then copy the `<@123456>` code and use that to have a bot send mentions.

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two options.

You can either use the `toString` method on the User object, or form the mention yourself using the user's ID.

[Here's an example using toString](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString):

```
client.on("message", => {
    const channel = message.channel;
    channel.send(message.author.toString());
});
```

And here's an example using the ID

```
client.on("message", => {
    const channel = message.channel;
    channel.send("<@" + message.author.id + ">");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `toString` method.

```
client.on("message", => {
    const channel = message.channel;
    channel.send(message.author.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023: Now you can use [`userMention()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/function/userMention)

```
const { Client, userMention } = require('discord.js');

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    ...

    interaction.reply(userMention(member.id));
});
```