# My mentions don't work, just send undefined

Tags: discord.js

how to mark someone, on channel send message "Hello xd undefined." help me

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    help: { name: "command" },
    run: (bot, message, args) => {
        if(!message.mentions.users) {
            return message.channel.send("bad, mention member!``")
        }
        bot.channels.get("587994214906724362").send("hello xd " + message.mentions.users.first() + ".")
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `message.mentions.users` to the console?

Comment: no, how? bumppp

Comment: `console.log(message.mentions.users)`

Comment: console log:
Collection {}

Comment: if i use !command <member#0000> that's work, if i use !command, that's send "Hello xd undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, discord.js interprets an user object as a mention. You should have this:

```
message.author.toString()
```

instead of:

```
message.mentions.users.first()
```

I hope I've helped :)

References:
[How to tag users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622930/how-to-tag-users)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome), [`MessageMentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) will always return a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection). This means that your `if` statement is always returning false, because `message.mentions.users` is indeed defined when no users are mentioned.

Instead of checking if `message.mentions.users` is falsey, check if there's any elements in the Collection.

```js
if (message.mentions.users.size === 0) return; // Or return your error message.
```

Answer (score 0):

try `message.mentions.members.first().displayName` or `message.mentions.users.first().displayName` instead of `message.mentions.users.first()`.